# how to print (on printer) table from database using c#

Tags: c#, printing, vb6, vb6-migration

I work on some project that is migrating from vb6 to web (asp.net). I need to print some kind of report - A table from database and number of simple headers with date and time. In vb it was implemented using vsPrinter object. Is there any Class in C# that is similar to this Class in vb6 in its functionality? If there in no such thing in .net, what is the easiest way to do this?

Thanx for assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be by using any reporting tool, one of the powerfull tools is Crystal reports, just google it an you will find alot of useful tutorial such as:

- [Creating Crystal Reports using C# with Datasets.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CreatingCrystalReports.aspx)
- [Crystal reports in ASP.NET](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/07/creating-crystal-reports-in-aspnet.html)

You can also find alot of useful threads about it here in SO under [Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crystal-reports) tag, like:

- [How to use Crystal Reports with ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370796/how-to-use-crystal-reports-with-asp-net)
- [C# Crystal Reports Tutorial on asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545298/c-sharp-crystal-reports-tutorial-on-asp-net)

Answer (score 3):

Remember you are moving to the web so you don't have access to the hardware printer controls.  You only have access to what the browser gives you.  If you are not doing anything fancy with this you can do one of two things.

1. Since this is an ASP.NET webpage, simply create a new browser or popup and render your report as html.  The user can them choose print from the browser print dialog or you can launch it with some generated javascript.
2. Use the Microsoft Report and Report Viewer controls is you need more formal report layout.  These are available from your toolbox under the category Reporting.